# How to check error log while trying to start postgres

Tags: 18.04

Trying to start postgres using:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql@8.4-main
```

After that, command line just frozen, not returns error, nor success and postgres service is not starting.

Where can I check error logs, what went wrong?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4 was last updated in 2014. Are you certain you’re running it on an Ubuntu 18.04 system? 

Comment: @matigo - Yes, I installed specifically that version (followed this  steps:https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ )

Comment: Is it in `journalctl -u postgresql@8.4-main`?